# Nuxt-ionic WebAssembly error on sqlite web using jeep-sqlite

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, capacitor, nuxt3

I am having these errors and warnings when I tried to use sqlite on web , I am not so sure if I have to setup the implementation in other place or way

**Errors**

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 3c 21 44 4f @+0
Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError: Aborted(CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 3c 21 44 4f @+0). Build with -sASSERTIONS for more info.
```

Warnings

```
wasm streaming compile failed: TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': Incorrect response MIME type. Expected 'application/wasm'.

falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation

failed to asynchronously prepare wasm: CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 3c 21 44 4f @+0
Aborted(CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 3c 21 44 4f @+0)
```

My current implementation I have tried to put it on the app.vue script or in a new plugin file

```
import {
    CapacitorSQLite,
    SQLiteConnection,
    SQLiteDBConnection,
} from "@capacitor-community/sqlite";
import { Capacitor } from "@capacitor/core";
import {
    defineCustomElements as jeepSqlite,
    applyPolyfills,
} from "jeep-sqlite/loader";

applyPolyfills().then(() => {
    jeepSqlite(window);
});

export default defineNuxtPlugin(async (nuxtApp) => {
    const platform = Capacitor.getPlatform();
    const sqlite: SQLiteConnection = new SQLiteConnection(CapacitorSQLite);
    if (platform === "web") {
        const jeepSqlite = document.createElement("jeep-sqlite");
        document.body.appendChild(jeepSqlite);
        await customElements.whenDefined("jeep-sqlite");
        await sqlite.initWebStore();
    }

    const ret = await sqlite.checkConnectionsConsistency();
    const isConn = (await sqlite.isConnection("db_test1", false)).result;
    let db: SQLiteDBConnection;
    if (ret.result && isConn) {
        db = await sqlite.retrieveConnection("db_test1", false);
    } else {
        db = await sqlite.createConnection(
            "db_test1",
            false,
            "no-encryption",
            1,
            false
        );
    }
    await db.open();
});
```

My package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
   "@capacitor/cli": "5.4.0",
   "@nuxt/devtools": "latest",
   "@nuxtjs/ionic": "^0.12.1",
   "nuxt": "^3.7.3",
   "sass": "^1.67.0",
   "vue-sqlite-hook": "^3.0.3"
},
"dependencies": {
   "@capacitor-community/barcode-scanner": "^4.0.1",
   "@capacitor-community/sqlite": "^5.4.1",
   "@capacitor/android": "5.4.0",
   "@capacitor/app": "5.0.6",
   "@capacitor/camera": "^5.0.7",
   "@capacitor/core": "5.4.0",
   "@capacitor/haptics": "5.0.6",
   "@capacitor/keyboard": "5.0.6",
   "@capacitor/preferences": "^5.0.6",
   "@capacitor/status-bar": "5.0.6",
   "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.11",
   "jeep-sqlite": "^2.5.3",
   "typescript": "^5.2.2",
}
```

I would like to mention that sqlite is working fine in the android app